# Newbie stuck on a jQuery question...conditional statement

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

So I'm a complete newbie and stuck on a conditional statement.  Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 if($('span.fc_cart_item_price_total') == 0) {
  $(span.fc_info).addClass('foo');
 };
});
</script>
```

So I'm attempting to see if span with a class of "fc_cart_item_price_total" has a value of "0", to then add a class of "foo" to the span with a class of ".fc_info".  This code above is not working.  Here's the HTML:

```
<span class="fc_info">Info 1</span><br />
<span class="fc_cart_item_price_total">$0.00</span><br />
<span class="fc_info">Info 2</span>
```

Here's the other challenge I have.  I'm trying to select the span with the value of "fc_info" before the span with the class of "fc_cart_item_price_total" but have no idea of how to just select this one span.

Comment: @user , your text has $0.00 right , you need to convert that to a zero before comparision

Comment: Remember that `$(selector)` returns a *new jQuery object* (e.g. not 0 or "$0.00" or anything else arbitrary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each cart item whose price is $0.00, this will add the "foo" class to the preceding (and only the preceding) fc_info.

```
$(function() {
    $(".fc_cart_item_price_total:contains($0.00)").each(function(i, n) {
        (n=$(n)).prevAll(".fc_info:first").addClass("foo");
    });
});
```

Comment: Very cool...I was actually looking for the coding that only allows the previous sibling and not all the previous siblings...thanks so much!

Comment: Not meaning to bitch about it, but my code also only affected the first previous sibling.

Comment: @sberry2A Not my intention to steal your flare here. I didn't see your answer before posting. In my defense, we've got slightly different takes on it, as mine deals with each cart row distinctly :-)

Comment: .. Absolutely agree.  In fact I +1 you for a legitimate and different answer.  Using contains, good idea.  Using each in case of multiple carts, good idea.  I was referring to the fact that the OP said yours was the accepted answer because of the :first modifier, which I added before you posted.

Answer (score 2):

Comparing with 0 is not the best that you can do. Try this instead:

```
if (!parseFloat($('.fc_cart_item_price_total').text()) {
....
```

Use ParseInt or ParseFloat depending on the data you expect.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that parseFloat would be a better option as a total price may be less than $1.00?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get the HTML out of the span.  Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 if($('span.fc_cart_item_price_total').text() == 0) {
  $(span.fc_info).addClass('foo');
 };
});
</script>
```

But then you need to compare it to "$0.00" or trim the $ off before comparing.

Comment: you have two mistakes in the code, .get('html') will that get only text , second thing is fc_info needs to be .class name...

Comment: Thanks, gov.  I found the text() error and fixed it.  I see your answer below, so I'll just leave mine broken so you can get the credit for having answered *correctly*.  :-)

Comment: nothing like that , i just mentioned so that you will know about it , did my comment hurt you or something??

Comment: haha; no I wasn't hurt; it would take a lot more than that!  (I just found your comment when browsing my SO activity...  (am I "vanity browsing??"))

Answer (score 0):

the below should work...please try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     if($('.fc_cart_item_price_total').text() == 0) {
      $('.fc_info').addClass('foo');
     };
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the above code working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 if($('span.fc_cart_item_price_total').html() == 0) {
  $(span.fc_info:first).addClass('foo');
 };
});
</script>
```

And to select the first class `fc_info`

Use `$(".fc_info:first")` as your selector